# How can I make the triangle in this program rotate?

Tags: pygame

Please be very specific , because it`s my first time working in pygame :D

```
#!/usr/bin/env python   
import pygame

pygame.init()

#colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0) 
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
PI = 3.141592653


size = (400, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("Professor Craven's Cool Game")


done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  
            done = True 


    screen.fill(WHITE)   

    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, BLACK, [[100, 100], [0, 200], [200, 200]], 5)


    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 25, True, False)

    text = font.render("Text", True, BLACK)

    screen.blit(text, [250, 250])

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Yes , if I have an error in this code also please tell me . I am open to learn new things about pygame .

```
clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Hello *criasmina*! Welcome to SO! :) Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your post (fix indent ...) so we are able to help you. :)

Comment: I have a triangle , and I must make him rotate . :)

Answer (score 0):

Try: `pygame.transform.rotate()` to rotate a `pygame.Surface`